# Selenuim.WebDriver ptor.get How to verify if page load was successful

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using ptor.get("someURL"), how can i verify if that page was loaded successfully, in instance like site is down etc.

The login site is non-Angular SSO login Page.

I Can do Element Find, but was looking into more proper way like Status=200(OK) etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
try{
    Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:/google.co.in"); 
    if (Driver.Title != null)
    {
        String pageName = Driver.Title;
        if (pageName.Equals("Gmail: Email from Google"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("done");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Error during loading of Landing Page");               
}
catch (Exception){
    Console.WriteLine("Page not loaded within 20sec");
}
```

Comment: I am not getting Timeout, i get "Page not Found", I can look for some element in that page and see if the page loaded successfully or not. Was looking for some elegant way where i can check the status or any other thing(I can even search for "Page Not Found" text itself

Comment: I made some changes to my response above. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tested load page complete, it works in selenium 3.14.2

```
    public static void Until(IWebDriver driver, Func<IWebDriver, Boolean> waitCondition, long timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
        webDriverWait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds);
        try
        {
            webDriverWait.Until(waitCondition);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    public static void UntilPageLoadComplete(IWebDriver driver, long timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        Until(driver, (d) =>
        {
            Boolean isPageLoaded = (Boolean)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete");
            if (!isPageLoaded) Console.WriteLine("Document is loading");
            return isPageLoaded;
        }, timeoutInSeconds);
    }
```